# Hair, eyes, moustache, etc don't move in sync with the head when posing head

Tags: rigging

I've been trying to rig this model, and most of it is working fine, but the trouble is when I move the head bone the moustache leaves the upper lip and the eyes start popping out. I've tried parenting them to the head (they don't move at all if do that). At the moment I've got it so that the eyes and moustache are both maximum weighting with the head bone vertex group, and that has got them succesfully moving with the head bone, but they still pop out of the head. I've tried making it so that the areas around the moustache and eyes on the head are completely red in weight painting, but that doesn't stop them popping out and makes the head move weirdly when looking down.

Problems in images below.[image]

leaving the head weighted as it is automatically
[image]

making sure the front of the face including areas around eyes and moustache are completley red in weight paint
[image]

Comment: the moustache must be part of another vertex group, so select it, on the menu on the right of the vertex groups click on Remove from All Groups and reassign it to the head bone

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for your reply but I'm afraid there moustache object only has one vertex group, which is head. I should have clarified earlier the eyes and moustache are seperate objects so they can be given different materials in unity

Comment: so maybe you need to deparent the moustache from the head bone, select the moustache and go into the Object panel > Relations

Comment: @moonboots removing the moustache's parent hasn't changed anything

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots here you go, thanks if you can take a look at it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UWXvfjGJ0YHTpCdfjfJmAYDi0N9DSmR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: actually it's your head that is deformed, so you need to either change its weights, or join the moustache to the body (but you says that it must be another object), or parent the moustache to 3 vertices under the nose (but does Unity keep the parenting)

Comment: @moonboots You're right it is the weights - not the head weights but the weights on the neck bone. It doesn't look perfect but the moustache stays on the head so I'll just mess around with it until it looks good - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's your head that is deformed, whereas the moustache follows the head bone correctly. What you can do is select this part of your head (or more), select the *Neck* vertex group and click on *Remove*:

[image]

[image]